# Trying to convert PIVOT SQL into LINQ lambda exp

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda

Hi I was trying to convert this SQL

```
select *
from Incidents i join
 ( select IncidentId, IncidentStatusId, DateCreated from IncidentStates) src
       pivot
      (
       max(DateCreated) for IncidentStatusId in ([1],[2],[3])
       ) Inc
       on Inc.IncidentId = i.IncidentId
       where Inc.[3] is null
```

to lambda expression, so after much of trying I ended up to this

```
var vehicleIncident = _moiFleetContext.Incidents.Where(i => i.ClientProductVehicleId == clientProductVehicleId).LastOrDefault();

                var incident = _moiFleetContext.IncidentStates.Where(i => i.IncidentId == vehicleIncident.IncidentId)
                     .GroupBy(i => i.IncidentId)
                     .Select(st => new
                     {
                         id = st.Key,
                         status = st.Where(sta => sta.IncidentStatusId == 1).Select(s => s.DateCreated),
                         status2 = st.Where(sta => sta.IncidentStatusId == 2).Select(s => s.DateCreated),
                         statu3 = st.Where(sta => sta.IncidentStatusId == 3).Select(s => s.DateCreated)

                     }).ToList();
                if (incident.Where(i => i.statu3 == null) != null)
                {
                    throw new MoiFleetException("Please work");
                }
```

It does not work, I don't know why.please help.

Comment: *What,* specifically, doesn't work correctly?  Do you get an error?  Do you throw the exception?  Does the data not have equivalent returns/results?

Comment: It does not throw that exception.

Comment: Please [edit] what the issue is, into your question and provide any errors or debug visibility you have on the problem.

Comment: Thanks buddy, but it works. cheers

Comment: @gravity I used this easy code to get a solution. var vehicleIncident = _moiFleetContext.Incidents.Where(i => i.ClientProductVehicleId == clientProductVehicleId).ToList().LastOrDefault();

            var vehicleIncidentState = _moiFleetContext.IncidentStates.Where(i => i.IncidentId == vehicleIncident.IncidentId).ToList().LastOrDefault();

            if (vehicleIncidentState.IncidentStatusId != 3)
            {
                throw new MoiFleetException("Please work");
            }

Comment: If you've figured it out, you can actually submit an answer (yourself), and accept it after a grace period passed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var vehicleIncident = _moiFleetContext.Incidents.Where(i => i.ClientProductVehicleId == clientProductVehicleId).ToList().LastOrDefault();

 var vehicleIncidentState = _moiFleetContext.IncidentStates.Where(i => i.IncidentId == vehicleIncident.IncidentId).ToList().LastOrDefault(); 

if (vehicleIncidentState.IncidentStatusId != 3) 
{ 
throw new MoiFleetException("Please work"); 
}
```

this goes to the DB and get the incidents where ClientProductVehicleId equals to the one received and returns the last incident.
and take the last incident to get their incident states. if the  incident state is not the last one (3) throw the exception.